# How to launch Camera when the screen wakes up or the lock button is pressed

Tags: android

I am developing an app which can be assumed as a phone lock app.My app initially sets a lock image set by the user and then starts running in service.I  just want to start camera and click a photo when i wake up my screen.I have been searching for this since a week.Please help.I am attaching my code along with this question.

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btncam;
    private ImageView imgcam;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE=1;
    private  Uri imguri;
    private File f2;
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btncam=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btncam);
        imgcam=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgcam);

        if(!hasCamera())
        {
            btncam.setEnabled(false);
        }

        f2=getOutputMediaFile();
        imguri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", f2);

        if(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imguri.getPath())!=null)
        {
            startService();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"no lock set....please set a lock image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        btncam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imguri);
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        });
    }

    File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG.png");

    }

    private boolean hasCamera()
    {
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY);
    }

    public void startService()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void stopService()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MyService.class);
        stopService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imguri.getPath());
            imgcam.setImageBitmap(b);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Lock saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startService();
        }
    }
}
```

Myservice.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new LockReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        boolean isPhoneLocked = myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
        if(isPhoneLocked==true)
        {
            Log.v("result","phone is locked");
            //Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"Phone is locked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
            if (!screenOn) {
                // YOUR CODE
                Log.v("ans","phone wakes up");
            } else {
                // YOUR CODE
                Log.v("ans","phone sleeping");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.v("result","phone is unlocked");
            //Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"Phone is not locked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
        restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        myAlarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +10, restartPendingIntent);
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

LockReceiver.java

```
public class LockReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
        i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.user.objunlck.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="set lock"
        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/btncam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgcam"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="/storage/emulated/0" path="."/>
</paths>
```

ManiFest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.objunlck">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <service android:name=".MyService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:enabled="true">
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

thanks...please do help

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are not getting ON/OFF events correctly.

The two actions for screen on and off are:

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
```

Here is code for Receiver:

```
public class ScreenStateReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.i("TAG","Screen went OFF");

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.i("TAG","Screen went ON");
            // start your camera activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Create a object of receiver in Service class:

```
ScreenStateReceiver mScreenStateReceiver = new ScreenStateReceiver();
```

Create a IntentFilter for receiver to listen to events (write this in Service's onStartCommand()):

```
IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver, screenStateFilter);
```

Unregister the receiver in onDestroy() and onTerminated() of service.

```
unregisterReceiver(mScreenStateReceiver);
```

To save the image in any folder, use **getExternalStorageDirectory()** in your getOutputMediaFile() method. getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type) will return the root path of the folder of that type, here in this case Pictures. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)).

```
 File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "CameraDemo");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG.png");

    }
```

Comment: Yes i was getting the screen on-off events initially also.Now i am able to open the camera when the screen is locked by ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE,which is my phone's default camera.But the problem here is that i want to store the clicked images by this camera in any desired folder.But the images are going into DCIM Folder.Please help.I am attaching the updated service class code here.Rest everything is same as the previous post...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyService extends Service {



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new LockReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    boolean isPhoneLocked = myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
    if(isPhoneLocked==true)
    {
        Log.v("result","phone is locked");
        //Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"Phone is locked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
        if (!screenOn) {
            // YOUR CODE
            Log.v("ans","phone wakes up");
            Intent in=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE);
            startActivity(in);
            Log.v("act","camera opened for lock comparing");
        } else {
            // YOUR CODE
            Log.v("ans","phone sleeping");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.v("result","phone is unlocked");
        //Toast.makeText(MyService.this,"Phone is not locked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Intent restartServiceTask = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),this.getClass());
    restartServiceTask.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1,restartServiceTask, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager myAlarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    myAlarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +10, restartPendingIntent);
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}